# Connecting Rails app to existing Mongodb database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongodb database with a single collection containing 400+ entries of basic data.

I'm using Rails and the mongoid gem to link the two together however when I query my model in the rails console there are no entries found.

```
 QuizQuestion.first
```

Yields no results

My model:

```
class QuizQuestion
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :question, type: String
  field :correctAnswer, type: String
  field :wrongAnswers, type: Array, default: []
  field :category, type: String
end
```

I have configured the mongoid.yml configuration file to point to the address of the database.

Does anyone know how to correctly do this or where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the collection's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons why you see no result:

1) database config is incorrect and you are pointing to a different database on the same mongodb instance

2) class name does not match the name for the collection within mongo. Open up a console/terminal and type:

```
mongo
```

then type this:

```
show dbs
```

This is the name of the dbs you need in the first part

```
use x
```

Where x is the db name

```
show collections
```

This will list the names of the collections.

Once you have the name of your collections, you can add this to your model:

```
store_in collection: "name_of_collection_as_in_mongo"
```

Therefore if the name of your collection was quiz_question as shown in the mongo client you can do this on your model:

```
class QuizQuestion
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "quiz_question"
  field :question, type: String
  field :correctAnswer, type: String
  field :wrongAnswers, type: Array, default: []
  field :category, type: String
end
```

The reason you are not seeing any records (if you are pointing at the correct db name) is most likely due to mongoid expecting the class name to equal a pluralised collection name so QuizQuestions == quiz_questions within mongo

Comment: Thankyou. The issue was that collection name in my database was named 'biology', changing it to 'quizQuestions' worked.